# Add main menu to dockbarx in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, software-recommendation

Since Cardapio is no longer supported in Ubuntu 13.04 can you tell me which main menu I can use on dockbarx in Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Cairo Dock, it is easily configurable and works on single and multiple screens.

To download it, open the Software Centre and Search for Cairo

[image]

or search for Main Menu:

[image]